# Security problem if Mac Os X file sharing permissions for "everybody" is set to read-only?

Tags: security, mac, permission, sharing

What does "everybody" exactly mean in File Sharing in the Sharing Preference Pane in Mac Os X.
Sounds as if everybody in the local network could read my files without authentication if its set to read-only. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user on your machine would be able to read the files. People on the local network can only read from the places you have set up in Sharing preferences (under file sharing).

Comment: @mrSchribbbt If I answered the question to your satisfaction, you should accept my answer.